# Object Literals vs. Functions

Tags: javascript, module, notation

I am unable to find an answer for the following.

My biggest concern is starting a project that is not supported on most environments, primarily browser. I have found that you can write modules in two different ways: functions or object literals.

**Object Literal**

```
var foo = {
    bar: function(){}
}
```

**Function Expression**

```
var foo = function(){
    var bar = function (){};
    return{
        method: bar
    }
}
```

The second option has the ability, to create private members, and from what I have found the first option does not. The information that I found also claims that the first option is an Object, while the second is a function expression.

Semi new to JS, so I may be getting some wires crossed. Besides the ability to make internal members private, is there any other differences in the notation? From what I have read, both are able to follow the module, observer, singleton pattern. The only difference I found was with the prototype design pattern.

Comment: You were using the wrong terms. Nothing in your question is at all related to JSON.

Comment: you have answered your questions already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several terms to know. First as it relates to functions:

**[Function Declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function):**

```
function foo(){

}
```

**Anonymous Function Declaration:**

```
function(){

}
```

**[Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#The_function_expression_(function_expression)) (where function is assigned to a variable):**

```
var foo = function(){

}
```

**[Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (the first set of parenthesis turn the anonymous function declaration into an expression):**

```
(function(){

})();
```

---

Now, aside from functions, you are asking about an **[Object Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals)**:

```
var foo = {
    bar: function(){}
}
```

vs. a Function Expression:

```
var foo = function(){
    var bar = function (){};
    return{
        method: bar
    }
}
```

or even a Function Declaration:

```
function foo(){
    var bar = function (){};
    return{
        method: bar
    }
}
```

You are correct about the Function syntax being able to create private members, where an Object Literal does not have that ability (it's just a way to group keys/values). But, another important difference is that Functions can be used as constructors (`var f = new foo()`) and can have [Prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes), where object literals cannot. As such, functions are often more versatile when it comes to setting up inheritance patterns.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, 'object literals' was literally the biggest block in my understanding of the concept.